# not able to install numpy in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, numpy, pip

error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy': Permission denied

---

Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip_build_mark/numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-TKmHYa-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_mark/numpy

Comment: have you tried running with `sudo`?

Answer (score 0):

Try running with super-user priviledges (via `sudo` or by logging in as root) or better still install in a virtual environment